# Cardinality of group generated by two matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, general-linear-group

What is the cardinality of the group generated by $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
under multiplication?

Comment: Hint: What is the order of the matrix you get when you multiply them together?

Comment: It's infinite. But is there a more specific answer? For example, is there anyway I can show whether it's also countable?

Comment: Any finitely generated group is countable.

Comment: Is there a rigorous proof of that statement?

Comment: It's not hard to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup generated by two elements $g$ and $h$ is the set of all words in $\{g,h,g^{-1},h^{-1} \}$, which is countable.

Now
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus, the subgroup is infinite.

Comment: technically, the group is a strict *subset* of the set that you mention, since words of the form $gg^{-1}$ are equivalent to the empty word.

Comment: @Rylee, I disagree. The set of words is the subgroup generated by those elements. Whether two words are the same is a different matter.

Comment: I'm happy to agree to disagree. I would have said the Klein four-group $\langle a,b, | a^2 = b^2 = [a,b] = 1\rangle$ has four elements, but the set of words in $a$ and $b$ and their inverses is infinite.